# Firebase-UI Web vs. Building Custom JS using Web SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

**Client Framework: Vuejs
Backend DB: Firebase Firestore
Auth system: Firebase Auth
__________________________**

I'm building a Vue application that uses Firebase Auth. In the past, most developers created custom form that collects user info (name, email, password, phone #, and etc.) using HTML Input field to gather Email and password, and then, from the client side we could perform TWO important actions in one sequence to give a single step to user.

1. USE Auth SDK to Call firebase auth method to create new user by passing email and password to the method as parameters.
2. Upon completion of this action, we then grab the UID that is returned by Firebase, and using Firestore SDK, we then make the next call to create a NEW User in DB, using the name,email, Phone # and the UID.

This flow works great which provides a smooth one step User Flow and we can provide proper error message and navigation.

Then came along and Firebase Team offered **FirebaseUI** to use as replacement to our custom form and sequence. The FirebaseUI has some strange behaviors related to how to "Sign up" new user and also lacks flexibility and a modern look for form entry.
Based on my understanding, the main reason Google wants us to use it:
**A) It provides a more secure way to collect email and password and send it to Firebase Auth.**
B) It provides easy way to use multiple providers.

My question is, Is it really unsecured to build our own form as I explained earlier and not bother with Firebase UI, when I'm only using email/password auth and passing it via HTTPS?

Please clarify, is it safe just build my own custom form or **SHOULD** I use FirebaseUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirebaseUI doesn't really offer anything special in terms of security.  Use it if you like the way it works. If it doesn't work the way you want, fork the [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web) and make it work the way you want.  If you want something completely different, feel free to implement it yourself.

The point of FirebaseUI isn't to ensure security.  It's to be convenient.  You are ultimately responsible for security, so be sure to audit any code you use in order to ensure it meets your needs.

Comment: Doug, thank you greatly for this clarification. Perhaps for a small and quick app, FirebaseUI fits much better, but for us not only it doesn't bring value, it gets in our way.